# How do I read the SharePoint ctype id from the browser url?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, jsom

Please see below screenshot.

[image]

I would like to read/retrieve the ctype that appears in the browser url. I guess this is doable using regular expression but I am not really good with it so can someone please help with the JSOM code to read ctype from the browser url since I am working with OFfice 365/SharePoint online.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the internal name you need, right?

Answer (score 2):

There is an in-built function in `init.js` of SharePoint to read Query String Parameter values.

Try using following to store in a variable named as `_ctype`:

```
var _ctype = GetUrlKeyValue('ctype')
```

Comment: Thanks @Yayati, can you add more details on how to retrieve ctype using GetUrlKeyValue, potentially store in in a variable using JSOM, i just need to know how do I integrate this in code, is there a reference I have to add etc.

Comment: You can try it browser console. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: I am sorry but it does not answer my question, thanks.